# Looking for missing cs files that are not in dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, compilation, computer-science

So I was brought into this project (C#, asp.net) which is already functional, but I need to edit it. All the source files are compiled, so in order to edit this I need all the aspx.cs files, but whenever I decompile the dll that is supposed to hold them all, I only get some of them. Half of the aspx.cs files are missing. I know for a fact that they should exist, as the site is functional. I have access to the other aspx files as well.

How would I go about finding these remaining missing cs files? Any clues as to where they might be located?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the C# compiler, but something to consider: Does the DLL contain routines that are never used? Are they being optimized away?

Comment: In general, decompiling should be a last resort. You should find the original source code. If it wasn't uploaded to the server, then it'll be on one of the developer machines. Get it from there. By the way, let this be a lesson to always use source code control software.

Comment: Its possible that the missing ones haven't been compiled into the dll, are they just loose within the site?

Comment: I found em, I'm dumb, just looked in the wrong dll.